# TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack not working when I was building a notification

Tags: android, notifications, taskstackbuilder

I did everything as the official docs describes. But when I navigate backwards, the MainActivity(parent) doesn't open. Instead, the application closes.

**here is my code:**

```java
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(TestActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
```

**the manifest is as below:**

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".TestActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".Main2Activity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: ok,i resolved it.the code is noting wrong.i delete my app and reinstall it then everything is ok.

Comment: thanks...saved my day!

Comment: Yeah really, it saved me at least an hour of frustration :)

Comment: thanks @Allen Vork :)

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: why uninstall works: Android is probably caching the PendingIntentwhen it finds the same requestCode... So changing that without installing might also work.

Comment: I'm guessing the Main2Activity was intentional as well

Comment: Can you add this as answer and mark the question as resolved? It will be easier to find.